# Higcharts: Arrow segment drawn with single click, can not be selected nor dragged

Tags: highcharts

I have my code in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/n21kofx9/43/). I can draw annotations with click-and-drag, using the plugins: user click and hold the mouse (drawing starts on `mouse-down`), start to drag around and drawing is completed when user releases the mouse (`mouse-up` event).

The issue here is: when we have a single-click in a certain point, an arrow symbol appears and this can not be selected nor draggable. In cases of single-click, will be ideal if `mouse-up` event to not complete the drawing and instead drawing to be completed on the next `mouse-down` event.

Here in [this video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crVoIB9nfN) we can see the behavior of how the single-click acts at the moment and also there I commented one condition to show how I expect this to behave. I am already successfully having the check if we have a single-click while drawing in the part with `console.log("this is a single click");`.

The two most important blocks of the code-snippet are given below, and what I don't understand is why this is not working as I described above, since I am already terminating the function in case single-click is detected (with `return`).

```
//on mouse-down event, if cursor is inside of the chart and if drawing tool is selected, set the 
//flag "isAddingAnnotations" to true and store the coordinates from where the drawing started
navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', function(e) {
  if (!chart.cancelClick &&
    chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) 
  {
    navigation.bindingsChartClick(chart, e);
    if (!navigation.selectedButton) {
      chart.isAddingAnnotations = false;
    } else {
      chart.isAddingAnnotations = true;          
      chart.addingAnnotationsX = e.clientX;
      chart.addingAnnotationsY = e.clientY;
    }
  }
}));

//on mouse-up event, set the flag "isAddingAnnotations" to false (since drawing ended)
//additionally, if drawing was in progress and if ending coordinates are matching with 
//starting coordinates, drawing should still be active
navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', function(e) {    
  if (chart.isAddingAnnotations &&      
      chart.addingAnnotationsX == e.clientX && 
      chart.addingAnnotationsY == e.clientY) 
  {
    console.log("this is a single click");
    return;
  }      
  chart.pointer.normalize(e);
  navigation.bindingsChartClick(chart, e);
  chart.isAddingAnnotations = false;
}));
```

Comment: Hi @delux, Do you want to support also `click` event or only `mousedown` and `mouseup`?

Comment: @ppotaczek I want to support `click` event as well. So if user do a single click (basically `mousedown` and `mouseup` are in the same coordinates) then the `mouseup` should not complete the drawing and we should have the default behavior which was there, before applying the plugins for modifying it. Therefore, as you can see in my code above, I was able to catch this scenario and I did a `return`, but even this block of code code is indeed triggered, the behavior is not as expected.

Comment: Hi @delux, Your idea with comparing coordinates seems to be fine, you need to only remove the current `click` event, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zh71knx0/